# How is this a mismatch between column count and values?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a MySQL 5.5 DB.  You're supposed to be able to insert multiple rows of values with this syntax:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c)
VALUES(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9);
```

But I'm getting an error ("Column count doesn't match value count at row 1") on the following query:

```
INSERT INTO users_X_shareItems (userID, itemID, userAction, detail, actionDate)
VALUES ('CB381FC5-6373-4D01-A2ED-01CEACFA750B'), 
    ('16nhbfsg6apltgtfhjkb29z4w'),
    ('like'),
    (''),
    (NULL)
```

Are my counting skills deficient, or are there five columns' worth of values right there?  In this instance there's only one row's worth of data; hence only one value in each set of parentheses.  But the PHP function that builds this query takes an arbitrary number of rows' worth of data, and that's a functional requirement.

PLEASE NOTE in the example at the top, directly from the MySQL doc, the parentheses supposedly tell the engine that these are LISTS of values.  Let's take that example and modify for an instance in which you're only adding ONE row's worth of values:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c)
VALUES(1), (4), (7);
```

The wording of the documentation is ambiguous, so I'm going to reorganize the query as some have suggested.

Comment: try this: `INSERT INTO users_X_shareItems (userID, itemID, userAction, detail, actionDate) VALUES ('CB381FC5-6373-4D01-A2ED-01CEACFA750B', '16nhbfsg6apltgtfhjkb29z4w', 'like', '', NULL)`

Comment: Are you sure that there are no left columns that are not mentioned in the query and that they are not accepting nulls or default values by default?

Comment: Thanks puredevotion, but that is not valid multiple-row syntax.  That will insert only row (which is all that's needed in this one instance, but the function that builds this query takes an arbitrary number of rows).

Comment: Thanks Rami, but there are only five columns in the table.

Comment: Your syntax in saying: Insert into 5 columns 5 rows with one column :). You'll have to learn basic SQL syntax.

Comment: Did you guys not look at the multi-row syntax example that's right there?  If you put values in SEPARATE parentheses, SQL is supposed to interpret them as lists of values for that ONE column, to be used in creating ROWS.  On THIS pass through the function, my lists of values are only ONE row long.  But they're still LISTS; that's what the parentheses mean.

Comment: @Oscar each set of parenthesis represents 1 row and each comma separated value inside a set of parentehsis represents 1 column. in your example you have 5 sets of parenthesis (i.e 5 rows) with 1 value each (i.e. 1 column)

Comment: Interesting, Fuzzy.  That's not communicated by the doc, but I'll experiment by reorganizing them that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the different comments I suspect you're making the assumption that the `INSERT` statement works like a function that accepts variable arguments (such as `COALESCE()` or `CONCAT_WS()`). That's simply not the case: is isn't a function and you need the same item count on each list:

```
INSERT INTO foo (a) VALUES
(?),
(?),
(?),
(?),
(?);
INSERT INTO foo (a, b) VALUES
(?, ?),
(?, ?),
(?, ?),
(?, ?),
(?, ?);
INSERT INTO foo (a, b, c) VALUES
(?, ?, ?),
(?, ?, ?),
(?, ?, ?),
(?, ?, ?),
(?, ?, ?);
```

... but never:

```
-- Not valid
INSERT INTO foo (a, b) VALUES
(?),
(?, ?),
(?, ?, ?);
```

If the table design allows so, some of the actual values can be `NULL`, but it isn't possible to omit them entirely.

If you need to handle different column counts, you'll have to build your SQL code dynamically. That's trivial in most programming languages.

---

Just seen your edit. You misunderstood the multiple-row syntax. It isn't like this:

```
-- Not valid
INSERT INTO person (name, age) values
('Abe', 'Bill', 'Charles'),
(23, 45, 17);
```

It's like this:

```
INSERT INTO person (name, age) values
('Abe', 23),
('Bill', 45),
('Charles', 17);
```

Comment: Thanks. The wording of the doc doesn't make it clear which direction the lists are supposed to go. Your "not valid" example is indeed the way I interpreted it.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you close the VALUES brackets after each single value? SQL know asumes you like to add 5 different rows with every row containing only one value but you said you will provide five values. So your Query should be

```
INSERT INTO users_X_shareItems (userID, itemID, userAction, detail, actionDate) VALUES
('CB381FC5-6373-4D01-A2ED-01CEACFA750B', '16nhbfsg6apltgtfhjkb29z4w', 'like', '', NULL);
```

**Edit**
If you want to add more rows in one query you still have to provide these 5 values. See this example

```
INSERT INTO users_X_shareItems (userID, itemID, userAction, detail, actionDate) VALUES
    ('CB381FC5-6373-4D01-A2ED-01CEACFA750B', '16nhbfsg6apltgtfhjkb29z4w', 'like', '', NULL),
    ('row2', 'row2', 'like', '', NULL),
    ('row3', 'row3', 'like', '', NULL);
```

Comment: They're enclosed that way because this is required for multi-row syntax (as in the example I provided, from the MySQL doc).  In this example I'm only adding one row, but the function takes an arbitrary number of rows' worth of data.  On one trip through, I might add five rows.  The next time, only one.  Putting the values in separate parentheses is supposed to tell the SQL engine that these are lists of values for each column, to be used in multiple rows.  A list with one entry is still valid.

Comment: Thats not true. If you provide a list of columns you like to fill you have to provide the same amount of data inside a VALUES list. You have to change your column list if you like to insert less data.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

However in your case, you made it like this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c,d,e) VALUES('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('5');
```

The total of items in the brackets must be the same with the total of columns, you inserted only 1 value for each row, that caused the mismatch error.

Just change it to:

```
INSERT INTO users_X_shareItems (userID, itemID, userAction, detail, actionDate) VALUES ('CB381FC5-6373-4D01-A2ED-01CEACFA750B','16nhbfsg6apltgtfhjkb29z4w','like','', NULL)
```

Comment: That's not multi-row syntax.  The syntax you suggested does not conform to the correct example at the top.  Remember, I'm only inserting one row THIS time; but that may not be true on the next pass through.  Enclosing each column's values in parentheses tells SQL that it's a list; in this case the list is only one entry long.

Comment: `INSERT statements that use VALUES syntax can insert multiple rows. To do this, include multiple lists of column values, each enclosed within parentheses and separated by commas.`  That is what is written in the doc.  Your syntax is incorrect, because you enclose only 1 value within the parentheses, while your table itself has 5 columns.

Comment: While this syntax may be wrong, the doc is not clear on which direction the lists go.  "Column values" may be interpreted to mean lists of values for THAT column.

Comment: @Oscar - Borth wording and example could be improved, but there's an example of invalid code right after that paragraph that implies so.

Comment: Actually, that invalid example doesn't resemble mine either.  It lacks parentheses for each column.